# How to generate an image from an HTML template in Python (to then print)

Tags: python, html, photo

I'm trying to merge/assemble 3, 4, 6 or more photos into 1 file from a predefined template to then send to a printer (photobooth style)

I have tried with the Pillow library, however, it seems to be pixel based and therefore rather cumbersome to manage many different templates.

What I have so far as a proof of concept is the below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from PIL import Image

#opens an image:
im1 = Image.open("photo_1.jpg")
im2 = Image.open("photo_2.jpg")
#creates a new empty image, RGB mode, and size 400 by 400.
new_im = Image.new('RGBA', (1300,1900), (255, 255, 255))

im1 = im1.resize((900,600), Image.ANTIALIAS)
im2 = im2.resize((900,600), Image.ANTIALIAS)

#print im1.format, im1.size
#print im2.format, im2.size

new_im.paste(im1, (100,100))
new_im.paste(im2, (100, 750))

#print new_im.format, new_im.size

try:
        new_im.save("img/new.jpeg", format="JPEG", subsampling=0, quality=80)
except IOError:
        print "Cannot create the the new image to disk"
```

How can I generate this file (thinking of generating an image) in Python based on an HTML/CSS template with some embedded images (while keeping a good quality of the photo to print and hopefully an ok performance too)?

Ideally, I would have an HTML file as an input/parameter with some placeholders and then, the python command would have X numbers of photos as additional parameters.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to generate an html page containing your images, and from it render an image (like a screen shoot).

There is a lot of libraries that can do html to X conversion.
Some use a browser for the rendering, other the browser engine (webkit, ...) and render in a headless fashion, and other again are in full python.

For simple html/css the latest can have the best performance.

Comment: Thanks Cyrbil. In terms of webkit I tried converting some HTML / SVG with  wkhtmltoimage, however, the quality of the output is not great (pixeleted). Do you know if is this a known limitation or do you think I'm doing something wrong? Chees

Comment: Ok, I looked at webkit2png and it works pretty well. The output quality issue I was having (I verified this with wkhtmltoimage too) was because I was providing an overall low quality. The webkit2png (~3 seconds) also performs a lot better than wkhtmltoimage (~15 seconds). Thanks for your help!

Comment: Glad you find something that fits you. wkhtmltoimage has options to set the output size and image quality which maybe could have solved your issue.